# How do i count users in mongoose who have specific criteria?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple ranking count that i must do in order to give my user a rank.

Goes like this:

```
this.model('User').count({'myClub.scoreStamp': {'$gt':this.myClub.scoreStamp}}).exec(function(err,countNum){
            rankToReturn = countNum + 1;
             console.log('rankToReturn',rankToReturn);
             deferred.resolve( rankToReturn );
        });
```

where scoreStamp is the scores that goes like this: 4.14, 3.11 and so on.

I want to add to this query another field, and check something like this:
Count all users which have the same X param, give me my ranking among them, i'm wondering what is the fastest way to do so:

Should i do a find first and then count?, like this:

```
 this.model('User').find({'myClub.club':12345678}).count({'myClub.scoreStamp': {'$gt':this.myClub.scoreStamp}}).exec(function(err,countNum){
                rankToReturn = countNum + 1;
                 console.log('rankToReturn',rankToReturn);
                 deferred.resolve( rankToReturn );
            });
```

Or is it possible to do something like this:

```
 this.model('User').count({'$and':{'myClub.scoreStamp': {'$gt' : this.myClub.scoreStamp} }}).exec(...);
```

What is the correct and fastest way to query such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the docs where both terms are true, put both terms into the same conditions object of your original `count` call which provides an implicit AND query:

```js
this.model('User').count({
    'myClub.club':12345678, 
    'myClub.scoreStamp': {'$gt':this.myClub.scoreStamp}
}).exec(function(err,countNum){
     rankToReturn = countNum + 1;
     console.log('rankToReturn',rankToReturn);
     deferred.resolve( rankToReturn );
});
```